# Update javascript file defining array while looping though said array?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm building a simple website which will show photos like a slideshow. The photos are uploaded automatically to the server at unpredictable times. Currently I'm running a cron job every minute to make a javascript file containing a list of the photos' filenames as an array. On the webpage I reference this file and display the photos listed in the array one at a time. Currently, this part works fine.

I would like to have the web page periodically check to see if the javascript file defining the array has had any additions since grabbing the file at the initial load. If there are additions, the web page should start over at the beginning of the list and show the newest photos.

Is there a simple way to do this?

This is the webpage:

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
   body {background: black;} 
</style>         
<script src="imageList.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function switchImage() {
      document.getElementById("body").innerHTML='<img id="main" src="photos/' + imageList[i] + '"/>';
      i++;
      if (i>=imageList.length) { i=0; }
   }

i=0;
setInterval(function(){switchImage()},45000);

</script>      
<title>SlideShow</title></head>
<body id="body">
</body>
</html>
```

This is the script I'm running to generate the list of photos as a javascript array in imageList.js:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
printf "var imageList = new Array();\n" > /var/www/htdocs/example.com/imageList.js
count=0
for file in `ls /var/www/htdocs/example.com/photos/`;
do
   printf 'imageList[%s] = "%s";\n' $count $file >> /var/www/htdocs/example.com/imageList.js
   count=$(($count+1))
done
```

Comment: I suggest that you request for image file names using an ajax call every once in a while, say every 5 or 10 minutes. then if the list is different add the new file names to the current list. this is safer. but if you want to use a hack-like solution without a server, you can try using number file names and iterate over them until there is an image that doesn't have image properties (height/ width ..) or any detection you can use then you will reset the counter to 0 and go on.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing my script to generate an xml file rather than a javascript file, and I'm using an ajax call to get the xml file every few minutes. From the xml entries I create a javascript array. Before creating the array though, I check to see if the number of xml entries is the same as the number of entries currently in the javascript array.

Comment: don't use xml for that, use json file, better.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I've already got it coded and working well enough for now! I will kiip json in mind for next time though.